# Add bootstrap and jQuery to Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to add bootstrap and jquery to my first project. I run this code on my project dir 
`npm install bootstrap@3 jquery --save`

It was run perfectly and added jquery and bootstrap to **node_modules** folder. And these lines can see under the `dependencies` in package.json

```
 "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
 "jquery": "^3.4.1",
```

Then parts were added to the `styles` and `scripts` in the **angular.json** file.

```
    "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
       ],
       "scripts": [
           "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
           "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
       ]
```

But Case is Bootstrap  not work for the views

```
      <form >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in!</button>
        </form>
```

**Output->**

[image]

Could I know the mistake I have done?

Comment: Would seriously recommend Bootstrap 4 which is the latest version. Is there any reason for using 3?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial. I will update it to Bootstrap 4. thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your styles.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: @KalpaWijesooriya, you're welcome my friend. be sure to mark answer as correct.